# REST API: Custom method using cookies and sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I am trying to use REST API, so I want get a @current_user in **APP2** from a RoR **APP1**.

In **APP1**/config/routes.rb I have this code:

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'current'
    end
  end
```

In **APP1**/controllers/application_controller.rb I have this code:

```
 before_filter :current_user

 def current_user
    if cookies[:remember_me]
      current_user = user_from_cookie
    else
      current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
    end
    unless !current_user.nil?
      default_current_user = User.find_by_id(1)
    end
    return @current_user = current_user.nil? ? default_current_user : current_user
  end
```

In **APP1**/controllers/users_controller.rb I have this code:

```
  def index
      ...
  end

  def show
      ...
  end

  ...

  def current
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml  { render :xml => @current_user }
    end
  end
```

In **APP2**/models/user.rb I have this code:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://APP1"
end
```

In **APP2**/controllers/application_controller.rb I have this code:

```
  before_filter :current_profile

  def current_profile
    @current_profile = User.get(:current)
  end
```

Now, if I Sign in my *User2* in **APP1** and I go to http://**APP1**/users/current.xml URL I get the correct @current_user (User2 object), but if I go to http://**APP2**/, even though I have 'before_filter's, the @current_profile will be always the default_current_user (User.find_by_id(1) object) instead of *User2*.

It seems do not care this code from **APP1**/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
if cookies[:remember_me]
  current_user = user_from_cookie
else
  current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
end
```

**What is wrong?**

*EDITED*

Maybe we can solve this problem through **APP1**/config/routes.rb parameters (?!):

Example: in **APP1**/config/routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'current', :current_user => @current_user # ?!
    end
  end
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a request to another website, the cookies of the current user are not accessible. The request is from server to server, so the application knows nothing about the user requesting it. I think a solution would be to send the parameters yourself and check for those.

Comment: I would like to access the APP1 cookies through the same APP1 (not directly from APP2) and then use the ActiveResource responce (not directly cookie information) in APP2. I can not send parameters form APP2 to APP1 (I do not know if there is a different [and unknown to me] solution to solve this issue) because, as you can deduce from the code and for the usage that I want to do for it, I do not know them before I get @current_user in APP1.

Comment: This is an insecure approach unless you use a certificate (SSL or TSL).

Answer (score 0):

If APP2 requests something from the APP1 via ActiveResource it is not the same as the APP1 logged in user requesting it. Users cookies are not 'forwarded'. Somebody correct me if this is nonsense. :)

Authentication part here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html has a couple of valid options listed.

Comment: I know that Users cookies are not 'forwarded', but I would like to access the APP1 cookies through the same APP1 and then use the ActiveResource responce (not directly cookie information) in APP2.

Comment: For APP1 the APP2 request is sort of like not logged in user request ie. no session, no cookies set. You need app to app authentication between those two.

Comment: Do you know some technique/tip to manage/code an app to app authentication like in my case? (I seen the http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource but I think that is not my case)

Comment: You may want to consider oauth