# Advice on how to implement a single login as facebook (eg: "Login with My RoR3 App")

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3

Facebook uses a button called "Login with Facebook" to authenticate a user or other applications. Also I would like to create something similar for my RoR3 application.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to achieve it, what technologies and protocols to use or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean such as [becoming an OpenID provider](http://openid.net/add-openid/become-a-provider/)?

Comment: I read something about OAuth. Do you advice me to learn to use that instead of OpenID?

Comment: @user502052: The two are actually very different things.  OAuth's biggest fault is in abbreviating "auth" which most people assume to mean "authentication."  Rather, it means "authorization" in this case.  Both can be used simultaneously to independent purposes.  See more: http://www.google.com/search?q=openid+vs+oauth

Comment: It is possible to use a my implementation (not OpenID, a third party application) to get what I want? BTW: what is using Facebook to accomplish that?

Comment: @user502052: You could roll your own implementation, sure.  I'd recommend learning all about OpenID as a matter of inspiration for your implementation.  Ultimately, all it means is that consumers of your ID system would have to conform to your standard and not the OpenID standard.  If the intended consumer audience is small and known to you, this probably wouldn't be a problem.  To my knowledge, Facebook currently implements both OpenID and OAuth.

Comment: My problem with OpenId is that I want a system authentication that not redirect my users to OpenID web site, but to my web site (a web service). So, basically, what I must to do is to implement something that make that possible on my web site. Is there a online tutorial where I can start to learn a implement this approach?

Comment: @user502052: That's exactly what OpenID does.  It doesn't redirect the user to "the OpenID website" but instead redirects the user to your website as the provider for the ID.  As a quick example, take a look at your Stack Overflow profile and click on the link to "add openid."  It will present you with a list of providers.  Click on a provider (Facebook, to continue with the original example) and you'll see that it takes you to Facebook, where it asks (in accordance with the OpenID standards) if you want to use this login for the consuming website.  It would do the same for your site.

Comment: In my case I (would) have a web service (UserApp) dedicated to users (where you can find basic info, login system, ...) and a web site dedicated to a RoR application (OtherApp). From the OtherApp I want to authenticate my users throught UserApp and I don't want use OpenID with Google, Facebook, ... login, but I want offer to all the possibility to login from exernal web sites. Maybe I aim to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533804/rest-api-custom-method-using-cookies-and-sessions, but it seems that "Users cookies are not 'forwarded'" P.S.: I am very newbie in this matter

Comment: @user502052: The more you describe it, the more it sounds like you want to implement an OpenID provider.  You just don't seem to be fully grasping what that means.  You wouldn't use Google or Facebook or any of that.  In the example of Stack Overflow's use of OpenID, your site (OtherApp, which internally uses UserApp for its data) would be on the list of providers.  The site(s) that would authenticate with you would be, in this example, Stack Overflow.  They would present users with a "Login with OtherApp" button, which would direct them to your site for approval.

Comment: In few words: I want that when an entity try to use a "function" from my web site OtherApp it must be authenticated throught UserApp. If it isn't authenticated yet, a window appear to do that.

Comment: @user502052: I'm afraid that doesn't really clarify anything (maybe better pseudonyms for your sites would help).  But, using OpenID and/or OAuth, the model is what you sound like you're trying to accomplish.  MySite would be a website which implements OpenID as a provider, internally maintaining login information.  AnotherSite would implement OpenID as a consumer, forwarding the user to MySite to authenticate and then accepting that authentication token for use on AnotherSite.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, but, since I am a newbie in this approach, I'm going crazy! So, can you advise me some useful resource where to start to read or see to achieve what I want (using Ruby on Rails)? If I understood something, I should create an OpenID provider for my web site UserApp...

Comment: @user502052: Honestly, your best bet is to read up on OpenID and how to use it as a provider (and as a consumer, since you may need to develop a site for that at some point or help a consumer of your site develop it), and to Google for tutorials on that subject.  The learning curve may be steep at first if you're not grasping the concept, but if you can reach that "ah-ha" moment and understand the structure of what you're doing, the rest will come very easily.